# Convert One Storage unit to Another in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have been trying to write a function to convert one storage unit to another, something like this:

```
function convertUnit(size,source_unit,target_unit){
  ...
  return sizeInTargetUnit+" "+target_unit
}
```

For example:

```
Input:  convertUnit(512,"Byte","Kb")    //convert 512Bytes to Kb
Output: 0.512 Kb

Input:  convertUnit(712,"Kb","MB")    //convert 512Kb to MB
Output: 0.712 MB
```

I have built the function to convert from bytes to any other unit, but can't understand how to make both the source and target unit dynamic.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object where the keys are the unit names and the values are their coefficient for going to or from bytes. You then look the input unit up, use its coefficient to convert it to bytes, look the output unit up and use its coefficient to convert it from bytes.

```js
function convertUnit(value, source, target) {
  const conversionCoefficients = {
    "bytes": 1,
    "kB": 1024,
    "MB": 1024 * 1024,
    "GB": 1024 * 1024 * 1024
  };
  const valueBytes = value * conversionCoefficients[source];
  return valueBytes / conversionCoefficients[target];
}

console.log(convertUnit(52, "bytes", "bytes"));
console.log(convertUnit(900, "bytes", "kB"));
console.log(convertUnit(2.4, "GB", "kB"));
```

If you really want to be correct, then "kB" (kilobytes) is 1000 bytes, while "kiB" ([kibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte)) is 1024 bytes, and so on.

To make this more powerful and understand kibibytes, bits, etc, you could have it split the unit into two: the last character (bits or bytes, maybe octets as well), and everything before that (k, ki, M, G, etc.). You could then use each part to look up the correct conversions in your conversion tables.